# AWeber Api subscribers problem

Tags: php, foreach

I'm having problem in AWeber's Api with PHP,
see the code below:

```
$email = 'soeemail@somesite.com';
foreach($account->lists as $offset => $list) {
    $subscriber = $account->loadFromUrl("/accounts/$account->id/lists/$list->id/subscribers?ws.op=find&email=$email");
    echo $subscriber->id;
    break;
}
```

The problem is that $subscriber variable contains the subscriber information, and when I use print_r() or var_dump() it shows the contents of it, but when I try to print the id or anything else of the subscriber using echo or any printing functions, it shows nothing !!

Please help me fast, I don't know how to fix this.

Thanks

**Edit:** the `var_dump()` of `$subscriber`

```
object(AWeberCollection)#25 (8) { 
    ["pageSize:protected"]=> int(100) 
    ["_entries:protected"]=> array(0) { } 
    ["_privateData:protected"]=> array(3) { 
        [0]=> string(7) "entries" 
        [1]=> string(5) "start" 
        [2]=> string(20) "next_collection_link" 
    } 
    ["_iterationKey:protected"]=> int(0) 
    ["adapter"]=> object(OAuthApplication)#3 (10) { 
        ["debug"]=> bool(false) 
        ["userAgent"]=> string(64) "AWeber OAuth Consumer Application 1.0 - https://labs.aweber.com/" 
        ["format"]=> bool(false) 
        ["requiresTokenSecret"]=> bool(true) 
        ["signatureMethod"]=> string(9) "HMAC-SHA1" 
        ["version"]=> string(3) "1.0" 
        ["user"]=> object(OAuthUser)#5 (5) { 
            ["authorizedToken"]=> bool(false) 
            ["requestToken"]=> bool(false) 
            ["verifier"]=> bool(false) 
            ["tokenSecret"]=> string(40) "******" 
            ["accessToken"]=> string(24) "******" 
        } 
        ["consumerKey"]=> string(24) "******" 
        ["consumerSecret"]=> string(40) "******" 
        ["app"]=> object(AWeberServiceProvider)#2 (4) { 
            ["baseUri"]=> string(26) "https://api.aweber.com/1.0" 
            ["accessTokenUrl"]=> string(46) "https://auth.aweber.com/1.0/oauth/access_token" 
            ["authorizeUrl"]=> string(43) "https://auth.aweber.com/1.0/oauth/authorize" 
            ["requestTokenUrl"]=> string(47) "https://auth.aweber.com/1.0/oauth/request_token" 
        } 
    } 
    ["data"]=> array(3) { 
        ["start"]=> int(0) 
        ["total_size_link"]=> string(123) "http://api.aweber.com/1.0/accounts/******/lists/******/subscribers?email=******@******.com&ws.op=find&ws.show=total_size" 
        ["entries"]=> array(1) { 
            [0]=> array(29) { 
                ["subscription_url"]=> string(22) "http://******.com/" 
                ["postal_code"]=> string(5) "00000" 
                ["id"]=> int(******) 
                ["custom_fields"]=> array(0) { } 
                ["last_followup_sent_link"]=> string(74) "https://api.aweber.com/1.0/accounts/******/lists/******/campaigns/f*******" 
                ["city"]=> string(8) "Non" 
                ["http_etag"]=> string(83) ""******************"" 
                ["ad_tracking"]=> string(0) "" 
                ["dma_code"]=> int(******) 
                ["last_followup_message_number_sent"]=> int(1) 
                ["last_followup_sent_at"]=> string(32) "2011-05-08 14:26:15.099159-04:00" 
                ["misc_notes"]=> string(0) "" 
                ["latitude"]=> float(******) 
                ["is_verified"]=> bool(true) 
                ["email"]=> string(18) "******@******.com" 
                ["status"]=> string(10) "subscribed" 
                ["area_code"]=> int(818) 
                ["unsubscribed_at"]=> NULL 
                ["self_link"]=> string(76) "https://api.aweber.com/1.0/accounts/******/lists/******/subscribers/******" 
                ["unsubscribe_method"]=> NULL 
                ["ip_address"]=> string(12) "******" 
                ["name"]=> string(0) "" 
                ["subscription_method"]=> string(11) "signup form" 
                ["resource_type_link"]=> string(38) "https://api.aweber.com/1.0/#subscriber" 
                ["region"]=> string(2) "CA" 
                ["longitude"]=> float(-118.5752) 
                ["verified_at"]=> string(26) "2011-05-11 14:26:15.099159" 
                ["subscribed_at"]=> string(25) "2011-05-011 23:32:39-04:00" 
                ["country"]=> string(13) "United States" 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    ["_dynamicData"]=> array(0) { } 
    ["url"]=> string(77) "/accounts/******/lists/******/subscribers?ws.op=find&email=******@******.com" 
}
```

Comment: Can you provide us `var_dump` output of that `$subscriber` ?

Comment: I've edited the question, you can see the `var_dump`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in your `var_dump`'ed object, there is no `id` key in first level of an object so `$subscriber->id` is not a valid way to get that ID.

`id` is in `data / entries / 0` so you can access that `id` with:

```
$subscriber->data['entries'][0]['id']
```